# React set state and requestAnimationFrame within event callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, requestanimationframe

On a canvas onWheel event I would like to animate a canvas zoom in, redrawing the graphics on my canvas on each animation frame:

```
    function handleWheelEvent(e)
    {
        let count, previousTimeStamp
        const mid = (layout.left + layout.right)/2

        function zoomStep(timestamp) {
            if (count === undefined) {
                count = 0
            }
        
            if (previousTimeStamp !== timestamp) {
                setLayout({
                    ...layout,
                    left:  mid - (mid - layout.left)  * 1.01,
                    right: mid + (layout.right - mid) * 1.01
                })
                count++
            }
        
            if (count < 10) {
                previousTimeStamp = timestamp
                // ISSUE - layout is not actually set when canvas is redrawn!
                requestAnimationFrame(zoomStep)
            }
        }
        
        requestAnimationFrame(zoomStep);
    }
```

The canvas is redrawn 10 times, but the `layout` state is the same each time it is drawn - and `layout` is only updated when the animation is finished.